# Draft not working in ucthesis package

Tags: latex

The following should single space my document:

> \documentclass[11pt,draft]{ucthesis}

and the following should double space it:

> \documentclass[11pt, final]{ucthesis}

when in fact they both result in a double spaced document. Does anyone know how to fix this? (I am running auctex - emacs - livetex - ubuntu.)

Comment: If `ucthesis` is a class local to your university or university system, then you're probably better off asking someone else who has used it. Otherwise, you might want to read the class code, to see how it is handling the `draft` and `final` options.

Comment: I'm actually using `\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,draft]{report}` to typeset boxes with imag adresses instead of typesetting images.

it works same way in LaTeX, csLaTeX, pdfLaTeX and pdfcsLaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At UC Berkeley (possibly UC-wide?), they changed the format for dissertations with the online submission system, from double to single spaced.  There is a command in the ucthesis class to change to single spacing, just add it before the start of the dissertation text and after the Front Matter:

```
\ssp

\begin{dissertationText}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\baselineskip = .7\baselineskip
```